# Calculo en powerBI

Tags: powerbi

tengo una tabla de datos de la cual genero 2 vista de matrices.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora necesito por cada registro de la matriz 2 dividirlo por el valor de la matriz 1, es decir cada cuenta de la matriz 2 en enero dividirlo por 5.792.304,10 y en febrero por 9.682.465,48 y así sucesivamente, el problema me surge que me toma los valores de la cuenta matriz2 por lo que se divide por si mismo. alguna sugerencia

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].